# Show notification numbers on tab items

Tags: delphi, notifications, icons, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I have a tab-oriented Firemonkey multi-platform application. I have some tabs which might have individual notifications. I'm aware of the Notification Center for mobile apps, but internally within my own app, I'm not sure how to do a similar indicator on tab items.

For example, I have a `TTabControl` with 4 tabs. Each tab has a custom icon. On each tab next to the icon, I would like to show a notification indicator, similar to that shown on the application icon when using Notifications.

Something like this:

[image: notification number on tab item]

How can I show such an indicator on tabs for iOS and Android?

I've tried putting a label on it, but there's no way of knowing how to programatically position that label when the form is resized / rescaled / rearranged for different platforms. If the `TTabItem` had a `Position` and `Size` property, together I could position such a label. But without it, how can I position anything relevant to this tab?

PS - Please pardon my horrific graphics :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to position a label over a tab item. It's a bit sloppy, but it works. First of all, the `TTabControl.TabPosition` must NOT be `PlatformDefault`. It must be either `Top` or `Bottom`. Secondly, the label must reside in the same parent control as the `TTabControl`. Then, implement a function like so:

```
procedure TfrmMain.PositionNotifyLabel(ALabel: TLabel; ATabItem: TTabItem);
var
  TabLeft, TabTop: Single;
  X: Integer;
  T: TTabItem;
  TabControl: TTabControl;
begin
  TabControl:= ATabItem.TabControl;
  //Calculate left position of tab
  TabLeft:= 0;
  for X := 0 to TabControl.TabCount-1 do begin
    T:= TabControl.Tabs[X];
    if T = ATabItem then Break;
    TabLeft:= TabLeft + T.Width;
  end;
  case TabControl.TabPosition of
    TTabPosition.Top: begin
      TabTop:= 0;
    end;
    TTabPosition.Bottom: begin
      TabTop:= TabControl.Height - TabControl.TabHeight;
    end;
    else begin
      //Not Supported
      TabTop:= 0;
    end;
  end;
  //Calculate label width based on tab width
  ALabel.Width:= ATabItem.Width / 3;
  //Position label to calculated Left/Top positions
  ALabel.Position.X:= TabLeft + ATabItem.Width - ALabel.Width;
  ALabel.Position.Y:= TabTop;
  ALabel.BringToFront;
end;
```

Call this function on form show and on form resize like so:

```
PositionNotifyLabel(lblCartNotify, tabCart);
```

[image: iOS Sample]

[image: Android Sammple]

[image: Windows Sample]